# No Sound on Ubuntu 20.04 with Intel Audio on Dell Inspiron Laptop

Tags: 20.04, sound, dell, intel

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Dell Inspiron laptop, which comes with Intel audio. However, I am experiencing issues with sound output. The system is showing "dummy audio" and I'm not able to hear any sound. I have tried troubleshooting this problem on my own, but I haven't been able to resolve it. Can someone please provide some guidance on how to fix this issue? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Please add to your question what you have tried the commands and any errors you get.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved the problem but, I solved editing a config file.

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

and in the section of options add this line:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-dock
```

and finally, `reboot` your computer.